# how can Reset Data in database after one hour

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a one project on server ,its a demo .

users can see demo panel and add and delete data in panel , I want each over data in data base reset and all recored which deleted by user recovery and delete all record whiche users add it to data base .

anyone do you have an idea?
My project :ASP.net web forms , SQL server 2012

Comment: Create and schedule a Sql job to do it.

Comment: Create a table with data that you want to refresh from every hour, create a sql agent job to truncate your current table and insert data from this new table with default data every hour.

Comment: @M.Ali can you add a sample code or offer requirement subject to do this. please

Comment: how many tables you want to refresh in your database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create another 10 tables to hold the default data that you will be using to refresh the data. Lets call them TableName1_Holding , TableName2_Holding  , TableName3_Holding, .... and so on....

Now create a Sql Agent job with the following code in it.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tables') IS NOT NULL 
 DROP TABLE #tables
GO

CREATE TABLE #tables (TableName NVARCHAR(256) , Holding_TableName NVARCHAR(256))
GO

INSERT INTO #tables
SELECT QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) AS TableName
      ,QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name + N'_Holding') AS Holding_TableName
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.name IN 
      (N'table1'      --<-- the 10 tables you want to refresh
     , N'table2' 
     , N'table3')  


DECLARE @Sql            NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Table          NVARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @Table_Holiding NVARCHAR(256);  --<-- Tables that hold data you want to refresh from

DECLARE Cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
SELECT TableName , Holding_TableName
FROM #tables

OPEN Cur 
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Table , @Table_Holiding

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
 BEGIN

    SET @Sql = N' TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @Table           --<-- Truncate the tables 
             + N' INSERT INTO ' + @Table              --<-- Refresh data from holiding tables
             + N' SELECT * FROM ' + @Table_Holiding

--    Exec sp_executesql @Sql 

   PRINT @Sql    --<-- test it first to see it is targeting the correct tables. 

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Table , @Table_Holiding

 END

CLOSE Cur;
DEALLOCATE Cur;
GO
```

Comment: Important Note. This approach will only work if there are no foregin key constraints and there are no identity columns in these 10 tables else you will need to modify this code to handle identity columns or foreign keys.